# SQL Triggers to find the difference between deleted value and inserted value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We have an application, which will work in the following manner, which cannot be changed.

1. front-end application will take the complete value of a table in a dataset.
2. We will be updating any column of a table from front-end application.
3. Application will just get the updated values (entire table updated values) and delete all the old value in the table.
4. Then it will reinsert all the updated data in table.

We cannot change the front-end functionality anymore.

I need to fetch the deleted value in the table and put into a permanent temp table from Delete trigger.
During insertion of updated data, Insert trigger has to capture all the updated values into another Permanent temp table.

After then from Insert trigger, we need to compare both the tables and need to execute certain function (ex:Function X()) only when a particular column 'X' has changed in value.

Please help me with both the delete and insert trigger in SQL 2008 R2.

Note:

- Table has 5 columns
- Column A,B,C,X,D
- A is the primary Key.

Comment: How do you plan to manage the contents of the "permanent temp" tables? Is something supposed to clean them up after the final processing step?

Comment: Does function X need to be called inside the trigger? Otherwise you could use the built in `Change Data Tracking` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and then call function X on a timer on the changed data?

Answer (score 1):

It is a very bad design, but so be it. Note the second trigger - it is INSTEAD OF INSERT. In the "ELSE" part, you will have to list all the columns and use their INSERTED.xxx value, except the X, where you will use the output of your function.

I expect, that the "TEMP_DELETED_DATA" table has the same columns as the original "TABLE_WITH_DATA". You don't really need the second temp table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER D_NAME
ON TABLE_WITH_DATA
FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

      INSERT INTO TEMP_DELETED_DATA
      SELECT * FROM DELETED

END;

CREATE TRIGGER I_NAME
ON TABLE_WITH_DATA
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

   IF EXISTS (SELECT X FROM TEMP_DELETED_DATA WHERE A = (SELECT A FROM INSERTED)) --leave new inserts alone...
   BEGIN

      IF (SELECT X FROM TEMP_DELETED_DATA WHERE A = (SELECT A FROM INSERTED)) = (SELECT X FROM INSERTED)
      BEGIN
            INSERT INTO TABLE_WITH_DATA SELECT * FROM INSERTED -- X DID NOT CHANGE, INSERT AS IS   
      END
      ELSE BEGIN --X CHANGED
            DECLARE @X [type] --DATATYPE ACCORDING THE COLUMN
            --CALL YOUR FUNCTION ...
            INSERT INTO TABLE_WITH_DATA --ETC.... INSEAD OF INSERTED.X, YOU INSERT THE @X VARIABLE
      END;

   END
   ELSE BEGIN

     INSERT INTO TABLE_WITH_DATA SELECT * FROM INSERTED --NEW INSERT 

   END;

END;
```

I expect, that only one row is inserted at a time. If not, it needs to be adjusted accordingly

BTW: the INSTEAD OF trigger, could be modified also to clean respective row from the "temporary" table, if it is no longer needed, after the "reinsert".

Comment: This doesn't look like it will handle an `INSERT` that inserts more than a single row, if it works at all.

Comment: it will not handle insert that inserts more, than a sigle row, but it could be changed accordingly. The principle is the same.

Comment: @HABO what do you see wrong, that you write "if it works at all" ? Maybe I overlooked something...

Comment: In the `INSTEAD OF` trigger you have two references to `INSERTED.A`. Since you don't select anything from `INSERTED` you can't reference a column in `INSERTED`. `SELECT X FROM TEMP_DELETED_DATA WHERE A = INSERTED.A` won't work but `SELECT X FROM TEMP_DELETED_DATA WHERE A IN (SELECT INSERTED.A FROM INSERTED)` will do something.